# WSO2 APIM 1.10 - update api status to "Retire" via REST-API

Tags: wso2, wso2-api-manager

I would like to change the current status of an existing API to the status "Retire" via REST-API.
I use the following methode:https://docs.wso2.com/display/AM1100/apidocs/publisher/#!/operations#APIsApi#apisChangeLifecyclePost

So a call look like this:

```
POST "http://127.0.0.1:9763/api/am/publisher/v0.9/apis/change-lifecycle?apiId=890a4f4d-09eb-4877-a323-57f6ce2ed79b&action=Retire"
```

But I receive the following message:

```
{"message":"Bad Request","description":"Action 'Retire' is not allowed. Allowed actions are [Publish, Deploy as a Prototype]","error":[],"code":400,"moreInfo":""}
```

In the documentation the "Retire" status is listed.
Questions: Whats going wrong? Which is the correct methode to change the status to "Retire", "Blocked" or "Deprecated"?

Answer (score 1):

The API should be in Published state in order to change into Retire State.

Can you confirm the current status of the API?

Comment: I tested several state-transions via UI. The affected API was in CREATE-State, first I have to change state "PUBLIHED", than to "DEPRECATED" and finaly to "RETIRED"....very complicated. Thx, for your support VizZy